# Mocking WebGLRenderer and other three js Libraries to test using jest

Tags: vue.js, dom, three.js, mocking

I am trying to mock three.js import and tried to create the webgl context using jest but I always get

> `Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'."`

this is because the webgl:- renderer.domelement does not return the canvas element in the mock. below is my code that I am trying to perform

```
jest.mock('three', () => {
  const THREE = require.requireActual('three')
  return {
    ...THREE,
    WebGLRenderer: class WebGlRenderer {
      WebGlRenderer () {
        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, logarithmicDepthBuffer: true, shadowMap: { enabled: true } })
        return this.renderer
      }
      setSize () { return jest.fn() }
      setPixelRatio () { return jest.fn() }
      setClearColor () { return jest.fn() }
    }

  }
})
```

Expected is, it should append the domelement(i.e. HTMLCanvas element to the existing document.body)

Comment: Hi Swathi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and to get acquainted with the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Regarding your question, some extra details would help complete the picture of what is happening. You included the expected behavior, but not what was actually displayed (even if the actual result is nothing). Also, check your console (jest _and_ browser) for any errors, and include them in your question.

Comment: this is what I get : TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

      165 |     renderer.setSize(_viewContainer.offsetWidth, _viewContainer.offsetHeight)
      166 |     renderer.setClearColor('#ECEDEE')
    > 167 |     _viewContainer.appendChild(renderer.domElement)
          |                    ^
     console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:621
      [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'."

Comment: Comments have poor formatting and limited space. Please edit your question to include your error instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I managed to mock WebGlRenderer:

```
jest.mock('three', () => {
  const THREE = jest.requireActual('three');
  return {
    ...THREE,
    WebGLRenderer: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
      domElement: document.createElement('div'), // create a fake div
      setSize: jest.fn(),
      render: jest.fn(),
    }),
  };
});
```